# How do I get an image from a blob url in JS?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a problem loading an image to a canvas from a file (image) input.  The fileInput object is the image picker.  This is all one block JS file on my site:

```
<script>
function picEditor() {
    var fileInput = document.createElement("input");
    fileInput.setAttribute("type", "file");
    fileInput.setAttribute("accept", "image/png");
    fileInput.setAttribute("id", "fluff");
    document.body.appendChild(fileInput);
```

Second part, the image is created.  The image and load button are created first.  The button's click function is supposed to set the source of the image to that of the file input's blob URL, then draw the image on the canvas.

```
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var loadButton = document.createElement("button");
    loadButton.onclick = function() {
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
    loadButton.innerHTML = "Click here";
    document.body.appendChild(loadButton);
```

Third part, the canvas and rendering context are created.

```
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.style.position = "absolute";
    canvas.style.left = "740px";
    canvas.style.top = "15px";
    canvas.style.border = "1px #fa0 solid";
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = 600;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
window.onload = picEditor();
</script>
```

My three visible objects are getting drawn, but the image isn't getting drawn when an image has been inputted and the load button has been clicked.

Comment: `window.onload = picEditor();` This executes `picEditor()` and assigns the return value as the `onload` handler, hence this should probably be `window.onload = picEditor;`

Comment: Thanks, I tried img.onload = function() {ctx.drawImage(...);} instead of ctx.drawImage(...); and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait till the image is ready before drawing it on the canvas

```
loadButton.onclick = function() {
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);
};
```

Comment: I get errorReporting: unhandledrejection: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.